# Reduce nested array to string?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I have the following array:

```
arr = [["Example"]]
```

I need to reduce it to just `"Example"` (basically, just remove the array).

I know I could do `arr[0][0]`, but am curious if there's a simple method to just remove the string from the array without using indexes.

For clarification...there will only ever be a single item in the array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a single item, you can use:

```
[['array']].join
=> 'array'
```

**Updated with more examples**

If you have multiple items, the strings will be combined:

```
[['array'], ['array']].join
=> 'arrayarray'
```

And if you pass a parameter to the `join` method:

```
[['array'], ['array']].join('&')
=> 'array&array'
```

Comment: OP question is just about one element.

Comment: Could be, but it could be just an example. I'm going to make an edit to clarify your answer.

Comment: @screenmutt it works for multiple items : `[["123"],["456"]].join` returns `"123456"`

Comment: @MarcinDoliwa Only if you want to combine the object, that wasn't specified in the question.

Comment: If you dont want, just pass separator `[["123"],["456"]].join("|")` outputs `"123|456"`

Answer (score 2):

While this is not as efficient as `[0][0]`, it will still work:

```
arr.flatten.first
```